# Execute tregsvr.exe through Delphi with parameters

Tags: delphi, server, ocx, shellexecuteex

I am using the `tregsvr.exe` program that comes with Delphi to register an OCX.

The reason for using this program instead of `regsrv32.exe` is that a `-c` parameter can be passed which would allow registration only for the current user.

I execute the program through the `ExecAndWait()` function, copied below. It uses `ShellExecuteEx()` (instead of `CreateProcess()`), precisely because (as long as I don't manage to pass the parameter for current user) I must ask for elevation and this is done by passing the boolean `Adm` which fixes `'runas'` (I read about an alternative way with the app manifest, but did not manage to get it working, maybe that is for another question).

```pascal
function ExecAndWait(const ExecuteFile, ParamString : string; Adm: boolean): boolean;
var
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  with SEInfo do
  begin
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := Application.Handle;
    lpFile := PChar(ExecuteFile);
    lpParameters := PChar(ParamString);
    If Adm then lpVerb:='runas';
    nShow := SW_HIDE;
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    repeat
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
    until (ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;
    Result:=True;
  end
  else Result:=False;
end;
```

In this example of usage, the variable `Path` is the full path to `tregsvr.exe` and `Server` is the full path to the OCX. It works well (it does the job of registration):

```pascal
ExecandWait(Path,Chr(9)+Server+Chr(9), True);
```

But my problem comes when I try to pass `-c` or other parameters, like in any of these attempts, where the function is unsuccessful:

```pascal
ExecandWait(Path,'-c '+Chr(9)+Server+Chr(9), True);
ExecandWait(Path,'\c '+Chr(9)+Server+Chr(9), True);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Normally when installing you simply write the registry keys when you deploy the app. You don't want to be shelling out to another process, and having to deploy that too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Mostly because I wanted to deploy in machines without administration rights. I thought that using this parameter -c for just "current user" might do the trick. (I use here 'runas' only for testing purposes.) Also regsrv32 was only working when the .ocx was in Program files, don't ask me why...

Comment: [`ComObj.RegisterComserver`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Win.ComObj.RegisterComServer) can be used for this purpose, together with [`RegOverridePredefkey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regoverridepredefkey) for registry redirection.

Comment: How are you deploying the rest of the application? Do you have an installation package?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The installation package would do just this, what I am asking about.

Comment: Since you have an installation package, don't call into a separate executable, simply script the registry changes required to register the OCX. That is the correct way to register COM libraries. It avoids dependencies on external processes, and makes uninstall simple.

Comment: @OndrejKelle I followed the links and it looks like the solution. Would you have by chance a handy usage example?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Chr(9)+Server+Chr(9)` is almost certainly incorrect, in a minor and a major way:

- The minor problem: Chr(9) is a tab. While that is a perfectly legitimate whitespace character, it's rather uncommon to encounter it as a part of a command line and as a result, I would not be surprised if the application you are trying to run failed to process it correctly.
- The major problem: If `Server` contains spaces, you will actually pass multiple command line arguments to tregsvr.exe rather than one argument, and quite unsurprisingly tregsrv.exe will not be able to understand them.

Solution: Put the argument into quotes to signal that it is actually one argument, not many: `AnsiQuotedStr(Server, '"')`.

Comment: Thanks indeed. I had committed two stupid mistakes: first, confusing Chr(9) with quote sign (now I remember to have used it often as Tab…) and second, not to mention that I had also tried with AnsiQuotedStr… Now I tried again several combinations with AnsiQuotedStr and it still did not work. However, incidentally I must say that my problem was solved by using a free tool "Enigma Virtual Box" from https://enigmaprotector.com/. It is free, it packages the ocx within the exe and allows you to use it without registering it.